# Access to the path 'C:\Users\mehdi\Desktop\sample\Test' is denied

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to load a folder into a winForm app. App should read the files in the folder and perform some operation on the files. Following is the implementation:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        FolderBrowserDialog folderBrowserDialog = new FolderBrowserDialog();
        DialogResult result = folderBrowserDialog.ShowDialog();

        var files = from file in Directory.EnumerateFiles(folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath, "*.chunk*", SearchOption.AllDirectories)
                    from line in File.ReadLines(file)
                    select new
                    {
                        File = file,
                        Line = line
                    };
        string newPath = folderBrowserDialog.SelectedPath;
        if (!Directory.Exists(newPath))
        {
            System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath + @"\Test");
        }

        foreach (var f in files)
        {

            string path = f.File.ToString();
            string filename = Path.GetFileName(path);
            string s = string.Empty;
            using (StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(path, true))
            {
                s = reader.ReadToEnd();
                reader.Close();
            }

            string[] parts = s.Split(new[] { ' ' }, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries);

            using (File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath + @"\Test", filename+".txt")))
            { }
            using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath + @"\Test", filename + ".txt")))
            {
                string output = string.Empty;
                foreach (string st in parts)
                {
                    output += st + ",";
                }
                sw.Write(output);
            }
        }
    }
```

There is an error on line `using (File.CreateText(newPath))` saying:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll
>
> Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\mehdi\Desktop\sample\Test' is denied.

What I'm trying to do is, App should load the folder and read each text file and perform the given task (replace out-of-sequence white space between the words with comma) and then save each file in the new folder created as `System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(newPath);`. All is happening as expected but when operation reaches to writing files to newly created folder `Test`, it is not allowing it the access.

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: Just to confirm: When you copy the path into your explorer, the folder opens without problems or prompts and your application is running ander admin credentials right?

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer. Folder opens in explorer just normal. Application is running under Administrator credentials. Thanks

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer I have edited my question. Please have a go at it again? Thanks

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer All is working well except this line of code `output += st + ",";` which is slowing down the process with the large size file as you move up with the process. Can you improve it?

Comment: Since your requests exceeds the original question by far, it is unlikely to ever benefit anyone else with a similar issue. Since the original issue is resolved, it would be appropiate to up-vote and accept the answer of @vendettamit. If you (after trying yourself of course) have another question (how to improve performance when replacing large quantities of text) you should just open another question and apply what you have learned here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're using Directory path in `newPath` to create a file. Append the file name in `newPath` to create a file.

```
File.CreateText(Path.Combine(newPath, "<yourfileName>.extension"))
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can you please help in extracting the `file name` from the above code?

Comment: Do you mean the file name from selected directory? Check `string path = f.File.ToString();` it's the same.

Comment: Done that. Execution is gone past that line of code. But we have now been thrown to line `using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(newPath))` with error `Additional information: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\mehdi\Desktop\sample\'.`

Comment: Repeat the same solution on this line too. The code have same bug as stated in answer.

Comment: We're passed that error as well. Execution is now stuck with line `using (StreamWriter sw = File.CreateText(newPath + @"\Test"))` and the error message is `An unhandled exception of type 'System.UnauthorizedAccessException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Additional information: Access to the path 'C:\Users\mehdi\Desktop\sample\Test' is denied.`

Comment: You need to add the extension of the file. e.g. Test.txt in filename. if you don't then it will be treated as Directory which is not a file.

Comment: I've edited the code again. Please have a look. Thank you. Code now runs without an error, produces no output, and program freezes.